# String to Array to Registry

Tags: arrays, vb.net, string, regedit

I have the string:

```
46-C9-08-B6-E8-F3-47-CF-53-2A-77-02-C9-19-7F
```

I want to make it into an array so it looks something like this:

```
{&H46, &HC9, &H8, &HB6, &HE8, &HF3, &H47, &HCF, &H53, &H2A, &H77, &H2, &HC9, &H19, &H7F}
```

The finished line will be as so:

> My.Computer.Registry.SetValue("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Bohemia
>   Interactive Studio\ArmA 2 OA", "KEY", New Byte() {&H46, &HC9, &H8,
>   &HB6, &HE8, &HF3, &H47, &HCF, &H53, &H2A, &H77, &H2, &HC9, &H19,
>   &H7F}, RegistryValueKind.Binary)

It will be inserted into a registry as a `REG_BINARY` type.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim s As String= "46-C9-08-B6-E8-F3-47-CF-53-2A-77-02-C9-19-7F"
Dim parts As String() = s.Split(New Char() {"-"})        
Dim byteArray(parts.Length - 1) As Byte

For i As Integer = 0 To parts.Length - 1
    byteArray(i) = Convert.ToByte(parts(i), 16)
Next
```